# Определить тип прокси curl

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Может кто нибудь подсказать, как организовать эту проверку? на php curl

Comment: Что такое тип прокси ? Что про нее известно и причем тут curl ?

Comment: Тип это тип протокола, какой он использует. Это может быть и http/https/socks4/socks5

Comment: объясните подробнее что вам известно и что надо узнать. по текущему вопросу ничего не ясно. протокол обычно заранее известен вместе с адресом самой прокси